# Constructing a triadiagonal matrix in Mathematica where nonzero elements contain functions and variables

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I want to construct a matrix `A` such that `A[[i,i]]=f[x_,y_]+d[i]`, `A[[i,i+1]]=u[i]`, `A[[i+1,i]]=l[i], i=1,N` . Say, `f[x_,y_]=x^2+y^2`.

How can I code this in Mathematica?

Additionally, if I want to integrate the first diagonal element of `A`, i.e. `A[[1,1]]` over `x` and `y`, both running from 0 to 1, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
In[1]:= n = 4;
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
A = Normal[SparseArray[{
  {i_,i_}/;i>1 -> f[x,y]+ d[i],
  {i_,j_}/;j-i==1 -> u[i],
  {i_,j_}/;i-j==1 -> l[i-1],
  {1, 1} -> Integrate[f[x,y]+d[1], {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}]},
  {n, n}]]

Out[3]= {{2/3+d[1], l[1],          0,            0},
        {u[1],      x^2+y^2+ d[2], l[2],         0},
        {0,         u[2],          x^2+y^2+d[3], l[3]},
        {0,         0,             u[3],         x^2+y^2+d[4]}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think, this works fine.

However, how can I do the integration? Shouldn't `A` need to have arguments `x` and `y`?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, it did the integration and in the upper left corner of the matrix is the result, 2/3+d[i] oops, that should have been 2/3+d[1], edited and corrected now. and I can't understand why you think A needs arguments, it is just a matrix. You can extract elements with A[[2,3]], but that is the only thing I can guess you might be thinking. If you mean something more than that then you need to explain what you are thinking. Mathematica is NOT a normal programming language, if that is your background and where you are coming from. Many many things are different.

Comment: Sorry, I probably missed the integrate last time or it was not there. 
Suppose I construct the matrix once and later at one point of time, I would like do the integration. 

For that purpose, shouldn't I need to define `A` as function: `A[x_,y_]` on the LHS and then 
`Integrate[A[[1,1]],{x,0,1}, {y,0,1}]`?

Let me know if I still sound obscure.

Btw what does `Normal` do?

Comment: I'm getting a little more puzzled with each new question. A matrix isn't a function, it is just a place to store values. You could later assign a new value to an element, like A[[1,1]]=Integrate[stuff], but I'm beginning to think your confusion may be deeper than I thought. Normal does several different things, depending on what you give to it. In this example Normal turned a SparseArray  into an "ordinary" matrix. Read the documentation for Normal and for SparseArray. ALWAYS click on Details when you read a documentation page.

Comment: Sorry, I agree, I should have checked the documentation. However, I strongly suspect that you got me wrong. Let's not do the integration for a moment. I was trying to construct the matrix following your first reply (which got modified now), but it doesn't produce correctly. 


`n = 4;
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
For [i = 1, i <= n, i++, u[i] = i];
For [i = 1, i <= n, i++, l[i] = -i];
For [i = 1, i <= n, i++, d[i] = 0];

A = Normal[
   SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> f[x, y] + d[i], {i_, j_} /; j - i == 1 -> 
      u[i], {i_, j_} /; i - j == 1 -> l[i - 1]}, {n, n}]] // MatrixForm
`

Answer (score 0):

`Band` is tailored specifically for this:

```
myTridiagonalMatrix@n_Integer?Positive := 
SparseArray[
  { Band@{1, 1} -> f[x, y] + Array[d, n]
  , Band@{1, 2} -> Array[u, n - 1]
  , Band@{2, 1} -> Array[l, n - 1]}
, {n, n}]
```

Check it out (no need to define `f`, `d`, `u`, `l`):

```
myTridiagonalMatrix@5 // MatrixForm
```

Note that `MatrixForm` should not be part of a definition. For example, it's a bad idea to set `A = (something) // MatrixForm`. You will get a `MatrixForm` object instead of a table (= array of arrays) or a sparse array, and its only purpose is to be pretty-printed in FrontEnd. Trying to use `MatrixForm` in calculations will yield errors and will lead to unnecessary confusion.

Integrating the element at `{1, 1}`:

```
myTridiagonalMatrixWithFirstDiagonalElementIntegrated@n_Integer?Positive := 
MapAt[
  Integrate[#, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]&
, myTridiagonalMatrix@n
, {1, 1}]
```

You may check it out without defining `f` or `d`, as well:

```
myTridiagonalMatrixWithFirstDiagonalElementIntegrated@5
```

The latter operation, however, looks suspicious. For example, it does not leave your matrix (or its corresponding linear system) invariant w.r.t. reasonable transformations. (This operation does not even preserve linearity of matrices.) You probably don't want to do it.

Comment on comment above: there's no need to define `A[x_, y_] := …` to `Integrate[A[[1,1]], {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}]`. Note that `A[[1,1]]` is totally different from `A[1, 1]`: the former is `Part[A, 1, 1]` which is a certain element of table `A`. `A[1, 1]` is a different expression: if `A` is some table then `A[1, 1]` is `(that table)[1, 1]`, which is a valid expression but is normally considered meaningless.